# Use a PHP script to authenticate users on Linux

Tags: linux, mysql, php, authentication, pam

I have a web application running built in PHP using MySQL as database. I'm trying to give specific users access to a Linux system via SSH to perform simple command-line tasks. Since I do already have a database ready filled with usernames/passwords, I would like to use this data for users to sign in. I'm using the PHP function password_verify and in some cases one time passwords, so I am unable to use MySQL directly for authentication.

I would like to write a PHP script to log users in, something like this:

```
php login.php username password
```

that simply returns 1 or 0, or maybe home directories, permissions, etc.

I have read a lot about PAM & PHP, but this is about using PAM in PHP, and I want it the other way around. Using a LDAP server for this purpose seems a bit overkill to me. I am unable to find something that I need.

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: I'd skip php and go straight to mysql with something like http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That would require me to rehash all passwords I guess?

Comment: mmm that might be, supported formats look like : crypt,md5, mysql password()   cfr   http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/Documentation/package-readme.php?seemore=y

Comment: OK, this seems like the best way to do it :)

Comment: It's unclear if this is a development exercise or a configuration exercise.  Are you writing PHP code? if so this is off topic and the question belongs on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so my suggestion is use [pam-mysql](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/) which accepts [these formats](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/Documentation/package-readme.php?seemore=y) of password encription